# Spell check not working in frame title and block title?

Tags: miktex, texstudio, presentations, spelling

I am using beamer to make my presentation. However spell check is not checking the spellings in frame titles and block titles. How to fix it?

Comment: Spellchecking in arguments of environments is currently not supported.